# Generate a code using username password and current time

Tags: c#, hash

I am looking to generate a code that will be generated from the user's username and password along with the current minute, this will be done on a windows form application then I repeat the same code on a website, and when the users try to log in they will be asked for this authentication code if it matches they will be logged in.

I searched but couldn't find a way to generate a 4 digit code from a hashed string

```
public static string HashSHA512String(string Username, string Password)
    {
        string AllString = Username + Password + DateTime.UtcNow.Minute;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(AllString)) throw new ArgumentNullException();
        byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AllString);
        buffer = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed.Create().ComputeHash(buffer);
        return System.Convert.ToBase64String(buffer).Substring(0, 86); 
    }
```

This is what I have done till now I want to turn that long string into a 4 digit code. Can you please tell me what I have to do in order to generate this 4 digit code?

Comment: What do you mean by 4 bit code? Are you looking for a hash that can only assume values between 0 and 15?

Comment: what i mean like having 9210 for example instead of that very long string  which is being produced

Comment: Then I think you mean a 4-byte (32-bit) code.

Comment: Yes, sorry for not explaining so well i am only a beginner and don't know such terms.

Comment: So... do you mean a four *byte* value? A four hex-digit (two byte) value? If so, you can just take the last so-many bytes from your `Hash...` method and use that.

Comment: what i want is instead of that long string i have 1420 for example and then when the minute changes and that method is run again the code is different.

Comment: Yeah, you could just use the last four bytes from your hash of the values in that case.

Comment: Honestly, your approach is pretty naive. Even this very first piece of code `Username + Password + DateTime.UtcNow.Minute` is suboptimal from a security standpoint. If you really need a *one-time password* authentication, you better resort to a comercially available solution providing you are beginner.

Comment: How do i do that exactly? @ManoDestra

Comment: Instead of returning the base64 representation as a string in the last line (the return line), simply return the last four bytes from the buffer in the previous line. And change your signature to return a byte[] instead of a string. Not sure from your responses if you genuinely want a byte code, or a 4 digit code?

Comment: I want a 4 digit code, but i want this code to change if the minute is different, i couldn't find anything anywhere so i don't know if this is possible. @ManoDestra

Comment: You could add all of the bytes together and then do a modulus operation to ensure that the sum lands between 0-9999. And then just return that integer code. Or if you require the 4 digits just convert to a string and left pad with 0.

Comment: I tried to convert the line before the return to string and it didn't work, can you show me exactly what i need to do also for the left pad part because i didn't quite understand what you said.  I only require the 4 digits. @ManoDestra

Comment: I've amended my answer to include that for you too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amend your code as follows...

```
public static int HashSHA512String(string Username, string Password)
{
    const int RandomFactor = 27; // Added this to make the code appear more "random".
    string AllString = Username + Password + DateTime.UtcNow;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(AllString)) throw new ArgumentNullException();
    byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AllString);
    buffer = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed.Create().ComputeHash(buffer);
    int code = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
    {
        code += buffer[i] * RandomFactor;
        code = code % 10000;
    }

    return code;
}
```

This returns you a code that is between 0 and 9999. You can then create a zero left padded string from this code.

I'd recommend using the full date though, rather than just the minute for your hash to give you randomized results, possibly with some salt in there too.

If you wish to convert the int that is returned from the above to a four digit string code, use this...

```
public static string PadInt(int value)
{
    var output = value.ToString();
    while (output.Length < 4)
    {
        output = "0" + output;
    }

    return output;
}
```

You could call this within your Hashing method above and then just return the string, instead of an int.

Comment: You might want to wrap that for loop in a [`unchecked`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8.aspx) just to be safe from a overflow exception, it should be unchecked by default but just in case the compiler has itself set to checked the code will still work.

Comment: I'll amend it to take that into account. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks a lot it is exactly what i wanted :)